# Clamped cubic spline interpolation find the end-point of the cubic spline

Tags: real-analysis

[Numerial analysis Clamped cubic spline end points slope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XeWX.png)

Suppose that
$$S(x)=\begin{cases} S_{0}(x)= 1 + ax + x^2 - x^3,  \text{if}\space 0\leq x \leq 1 \\ S_{1}(x)= 1 + b(x-1) -2(x-1)^{2} +(x-1)^3,  \text{if}\space 1\leq x \leq 2\end{cases}$$

is a clamped cubic spline. What are the clamped end-point slopes?

Comment: Please type up your question instead of posting an image, and show where in your calculations are you encountering problems.

Comment: Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) on how to write a good question before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Since you’re given a cubic spline, you know that $S_0(1) = S_1(1)$, $S_0’(1) = S_1’(1)$, and $S_0’’(1) = S_1’’(1)$. Calculate the derivatives, write down the three equations, and solve them to get $a$ and $b$. Plug the $a$ and $b$ you just calculated into the formulas for $S_0$ and $S_1$. Calculate $S_0’(0)$ and $S_1’(1)$. Those are the end derivatives that the question asks you to calculate.